# Using 2 for loop data in 2 seperate column using jinja (flask)?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have two list generated from view . I want to render it in html to display as table  I ran two for loop

```
{% for row in country %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{ row }}</td>
{% endfor %}
{% for count in death %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{ count }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

country     death
★ United States 16,691  ★ Spain 15,447  ★ Italy 18,279

but I need to be like

★ United States 16,691
★ Spain 15,447
★ Italy 18,279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by comparing the index(counter) values of the two loops. Only when they are equal they will be rendered on a new row.

> The special loop variable always points to the innermost loop. If it’s desired to have access to an outer loop it’s possible to alias it:

```
{% for row in country %}
     {% set outer_loop = loop %}
     {% for count in death %}
         {% if outer_loop.index0 == loop.index0 %} #note that index start at 0
            <tr>
            <td>★ {{ row }} {{ count }}</td>
            </tr>
         {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This should do it, but I havent tested this; this is roughly the ideea here. You may also explore what's possible by reading on the docs [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/)

Comment: It gives blank page for me . no output

Comment: Are you able to debug this? Right before the if statement have this `{{ row }} {{ count }}` to see what is being printed out. this should lead you the right way.

Comment: That one is giving the output .

Comment: if this line {{ row }} {{ count }} is below if stat then it gives blank page

Comment: i have made a small change to the code. can you try that and let me know?

Comment: It remains the same . no output

Comment: I have country variable where all the country name is stored and in count variables  numbers are stored . when I run 2 loops seperately it gives the result in col-1 only . but i need country in col-1 and its count in col-2 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211349/discussion-between-a-ranjan-and-azycrw4282).

Comment: you are missing a `</tr>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the note melwill. It is sometimes ok to omit the closing tr tag and it works fine. The problem is still not sovled, so i really cant tell whats going wrng here

Comment: can it work for 3rd loop as well ? If i need another 3rd column

Comment: Yes, why not! You would need to follow the same logic but handling the conditions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off in your template if you merged the lists in your view.

In the view:

`statistics = zip(country, death)`

In the template you can now iterate over a list of tuples looking like this:

`[('United States', '16,691'), ('Spain', '15,447'), ('Italy', '18,279')]`

I'm not sure exactly how that works in jinja, but it removes the need for nested for loops.

Answer (score 0):

For 3 nested loop , here is the code

```
{% for row in country %}
  {% set outer_loop = loop %}
  {% for confirm in confirmed %}
     {% set inner_loop = loop %}
     {% for dead in death %}
        {% if outer_loop.index0 == loop.index0 %}  {% if inner_loop.index0 == 
        loop.index0 %}
      <tr><td>{{ row }}</td> <td> {{ confirm }}</td> <td> {{ dead }} </td></tr>
     {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

{% endfor %}